# Nginx location path matching

Tags: nginx, configuration

Quite simple, but for some reason, I can't figure out the right syntax:

```
location /ios/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /ios/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /cap/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /cap/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /aww/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /aww/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

I'm wanting to combine all those, with options to throw in more apps at the top level directory.

The setup is: each directory is its own app (code-igniter or laravel) and resides at domain.com/:app

I'm trying to combine paths here (prod site is Apache, using nginx here), but all my attempts to do this have failed.

I tried `~ /([\w\-]+)/  [...] /$1/index.php[...]` however, that fails. Just using `~ /ios/` fails (causes a page-download).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why does it fail? What happens?

Comment: @FaisalMemon Page-download. Or a 404. Page-download mostly. Very odd, like the PHP isn't getting interpreted, even though I have the standard \.php$ location catcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a named location to perform an internal rewrite to the correct `index.php` file:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)/ $1/index.php$is_args$args last;
    return 404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: Perfect! This appears to be working as expected, including php interpretation. Thanks!